# Android animatorset not working

Tags: android, xamarin, objectanimator

Im trying to do a animator kind of like IPhone coverflow but a little more simple. 
Now im trying to make a rotation and then make the image go fullscreen but nothing is happening.

```
            ImageView i = (ImageView) FindViewById(args.Position);

            var disp = WindowManager.DefaultDisplay;
            var height = disp.Height;
            var width = disp.Width;


            ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.OfInt(i, "rotationY", 0, 180);
            ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.OfInt(i, "scaleX", width);
            ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.OfInt(i, "scaleY", height);
            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
            set.Play(anim).With(scaleX).With(scaleY);
```

What is wrong with the code? why is nothing happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call [`Start()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html#start()) on your `AnimatorSet` to actually start the animation.

The [`Play()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html#play(android.animation.Animator)) method doesn't actually play the animation- it specifies an animation that the set should play and creates an `AnimatorSet.Builder` that you can use for setting up additional constraints (such as your `With()`).

Secondly, your ObjectAnimators are all looking for integer properties, but the [rotation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotationX(float)) and [scale](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleX(float)) properties require floats.

You should be using `ObjectAnimator.OfFloat()` instead.

Comment: Okej Thanks! But it is still not working :( is there anything else ive missed?

Comment: I've updated my answer- you should also be using `OfFloat()` instead of `OfInt()`.